# How to hide apps on google play store as a devoloper

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps, google-play-console

Is there any way to hide apps on my google play developer account, like the all the apps published by the developer?

Comment: do you want to unpublish it? or in the list of developer console?

Answer (score 39):

If you want to temporary hide your app from the Google Play store, you can check "Unpublished" in the "App availability" tab (see below)

[image: google play unpublished app]

Answer (score 1):

Here is documentation on how to publish private apps in the Play Store: https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en

Note that you will very likely need to create a new app. There is nothing you can do for your existing app.